# Cannot convert undefined or null to object js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I was working with a static .js file and this code worked as long as all keys had a value. I would like to feed in the data from an url. However, I have been unsuccessful in error handling for the "undefined" and "null" values". The error in the console reads:

main.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.entries () at SVGPathElement. (main.js:14) at SVGPathElement.handle (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3) at SVGPathElement.dispatch (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3) at SVGPathElement.r.handle (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3)

Below is the main.js code **without** error handling. I have been reading and trying to implement some of the suggestions on this topic. However, nothings working. One of my attempts is the second code box below. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
        $("path, circle").hover(function(e) {
          // make tooltip visible
          $('#info-box').css('display','block');
          // get year from selector element
          const year = document.querySelector('#myList').value;
          // filter the `data` array for states just in that year
          const filtered = data.filter(d => d.Year == year);
          // filter states of that year to just the one state matching the id of 
          // the path that is being hovered on 
          const state = filtered.filter(d => d.id == $(this).attr('id'))[0];
          // create the html string to populate the tooltip with 
          // as long as the key isn't 'id' then continue building
          let state_html = '';
          Object.entries(state).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            if (key != 'id') {
            state_html += `${key}: ${value}<br>`;
            }
          })
          // change value of tooltip to html we just made
          $('#info-box').html(state_html);
        });
        $("path, circle").mouseleave(function(e) {
          $('#info-box').css('display','none');
        });
        $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
          $('#info-box').css('top',e.pageY-$('#info-box').height()-30);
          $('#info-box').css('left',e.pageX-($('#info-box').width())/2);
        }).mouseover();
        var ios = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
        if(ios) {
          $('a').on('click touchend', function() {
            var link = $(this).attr('href');
            window.open(link,'_blank');
            return false;
          });
        }
        function getOption() {
          const selectElement = document.querySelector('#myList');
          output = selectElement.value;
          document.querySelector('.output').textContent = output;
        }
```

````
    $("path, polyline, polygon").hover(function(e) {
      // make tooltip visible
      $('#info-box').css('display','block');
      // get date from selector element
      const Date = document.querySelector('#myList').value;
      // filter the `data` array for counties just in that date
      const filtered = data.filter(d => d.date == Date);
      // filter counties of that date to just the one county matching the id of 
      // the path that is being hovered on 
      const county = filtered.filter(d => d.id == $(this).attr('id'))[0];
      // create the html string to populate the tooltip with 
      // as long as the key isn't 'id' then continue building
      let county_html = '';
      Object.entries(undefined).forEach(([key]) => {
      if (key != 'undefined' | 'null') {
        county_html += `$(0): $(0)<br>`;
        }
      })
      Object.entries(county).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if (key != 'id') {
          county_html += `${key}: ${value}<br>`;
        }
      })
      // change value of tooltip to html we just made
      $('#info-box').html(county_html);
    });
    $("path, polyline, polygon").mouseleave(function(e) {
      $('#info-box').css('display','none');
    });
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
      $('#info-box').css('top',e.pageY-$('#info-box').height()-30);
      $('#info-box').css('left',e.pageX-($('#info-box').width())/2);
    }).mouseover();
    var ios = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
    if(ios) {
      $('a').on('click touchend', function() {
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        window.open(link,'_blank');
        return false;
      });
    }
    function getOption() {
      const selectElement = document.querySelector('#myList');
      output = selectElement.value;
      document.querySelector('.output').textContent = output;
    }

```
````

Comment: why do you converting undefined to Object can you explain us?

Comment: I have an array of objects that are being filtered by user input and shown when mouse over(hover). The code is dynamic, showing the key:values of the filtered data. The static data I have is clean. However, the live data I want to use has missing values. The missing values throws an error and causes the program to stop and not work when hovered on. With the code Davidmwhynot suggested, the program no longer breaks. It holds the key:value of the last hovered on item, until the next object is hovered on.

Answer (score 0):

The loop on line 14 of the second file is the source of your error, and probably can just be removed (as I don't see any other object you would want to iterate through):

```js
      // this block can likely be removed
      Object.entries(undefined).forEach(([key]) => {
        if (key != 'undefined' | 'null') {
          county_html += `$(0): $(0)<br>`;
        }
      })
```

Instead, it looks like you want to check your `county` object for undefined or null values. That can be done in the loop you have following the unnecessary one:

```js
Object.entries(county).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (key !== 'id' && key !== undefined && key !== null) {
    county_html += `${key}: ${value}<br>`;
  }
});
```

Comment: Same error.  Although, your code looks very promising. I'm going to play with it for a while. Let you know if I find something. Thank you for the swift response.

Comment: I believe my problem is beyond the error handing code. I'm reading in data for my data.js file. It's console logging the data when being read in as csv. However, I believe there is a disconnect when I am trying to transform it to json.

Comment: ' const url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-counties.csv";

const data = d3.csv(url, function(data){
    
}); '

Comment: `function csvJSON(data){
    var lines=url.split("\n");
    var headers=lines[0].split(",");
    for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){
        var obj = {};
        var currentline=lines[i].split(",");
        for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
            obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
        }
        data.push(obj);
    }
    return JSON.stringify(data); 
    }`

Comment: Yes. I went to my original static data.js file and  removed some lines of data. Your error handling code works! I will need to revisit my csv to json code to find the break. Thank you.

Comment: @ShannonGoddard if my answer has solved the issues, can you mark it as the accepted answer? Thanks!